# What ceramic capacitor is this?

Tags: capacitor, identification, surface-mount, ceramic

I'm almost sure this is a ceramic capacitor, but I have trouble finding its characteristics.

The first picture is the top side, the second the bottom side.

The first shows: 120G (or 12OG)  and an F.

On page 4 of [datasheet](https://nl.mouser.com/datasheet/2/281/murata_03052018_GRM_Series_1-1310166.pdf) shows how to read the aprt number, but I cannot map it (maybe I have a wrong datasheet).

Can someone identify or give a correct datasheet for this component?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That looks more like a tantalum capacitor to me

Comment: @DerStrom8 That is possible too, it looked a bit similar to another component I have which is a ceramic capacitor (probably).

Comment: More like a diode.  Possibly Zener.

Comment: Not a tantalum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think for Surface Mount TVS Diodes LITTELFUSE NO?

Comment: It could be, they look the same, although I cannot find any 120g number (except related to weight) on their website.

Comment: It's definitely the Littel Fuse logo